# Visualforce not loading iframe after update

Tags: visualforce, email-template, customsetting, iframe

I had/have a Visualforce page that displays an iframe that points to another page within my organization. It points to the page that renders an email template (like `https://prodorg--c.na17.content.force.com/email/templaterenderer?id=00Xo0000000qhjUEAQ&recipient_type_id=003o000000rkJIKAA2&related_to_id=a00o000000uGVSE`).

I had to do a little tweak on the page, but didn't change the iframe section. Once I deployed the change set in production (NA17) the iframe stopped working, but it still works on sandbox (CS22 instance).

I don't get it. I've done some research and I read about clickjacking, and how Salesforce started to enable some headers by default that would prevent loading external pages or something like that. But hey, my page works on sandbox and not on production? And all updates are applied to both, so I don't see why the page won't load on production.

Now I get the error message (on Chrome's console):

> Refused to display
>   'https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fcontent%2Fsession%3Furl%3D…%2526preview_frame%253DcontentFrame%2526render_type%253DREPLACED_HTML_BODY'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a while, I ended with the conclusion that the URL I was using was no longer in use by Salesforce. It used `mydomain.visual.force.com`, and it now uses `mydomain.content.force.com`.

My solution was to create a custom setting that would hold this base URL so it could be used on other pages. In the end, my iframe code ended up like:

```
<iframe src="https://{!$Setup.MyGlobalVar__c.MyVFContentBaseURL__c}/email/templaterenderer?id={!template.Id}&recipient_type_id={!email.WhoId}&related_to_id={!Id}&base_href=https://{!$Setup.MyGlobalVar__c.MyVFContentBaseURL__c}/.salesforce.com&preview_frame=contentFrame&render_type=REPLACED_HTML_BODY" width="100%" height="600px" />
```